# Combine fields into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data set:

```
user_id | advr1_id | advr1_name | advr2_id | advr2_name | advr3_id | advr3_name
--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------
      7 |       22 | John Smith |       15 |   Jane Doe |        9 | Bill Clint
      8 |       15 |   Jane Doe |       10 |    Kim Gol |     null | null
```

I want to make another column `advrs` that contains all the advr names (this would be at the placed into the record above).

```
user_id | advrs
--------+---------------------------------
      7 | John Smith; Jane Doe; Bill Clint
      8 | Jane Doe; Kim Gol
```

I can achieve this with `listagg()` but it is super slow... is there an alternative method I don't know about?

Comment: I could potentially use `advr1_name || '; ' || advr2_name` ? But would I need a case statement to take into account null values or can I use `nvl()` in some way?

Comment: I tried this method, but it is just as slow if not slower than listagg().

Comment: You can use [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) instead of nvl. But I think you should consider your data set, add some range filters, or indexes, the query itself is slow, the listagg and the case combined with coalesce will not help, in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
select user_id, 
       replace(
           listagg(
               advr1_name 
               || decode(advr2_name, null, '', '# ' || advr2_name)
               || decode(advr3_name, null, '', '# ' || advr3_name)
               , '; '
               ) within group (order by advr1_name), 
           '#', ';'
       )
from your_tab
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty or terribly efficient, and not exactly scalable if you ever add `advr4...` or more, but this might do the job quicker than listagg:

```
ltrim(rtrim(replace(advr1_name||'; '||advr2_name||'; '||advr3_name, '; ; ', '; '), '; '),'; ')
```